# requisitando todos os arquivos principais do node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm

Eu tenho instalado algumas dependências com o `NPM`, essas dependências são básicas, como bootstrap, animatecss e outras...

Enfim, gostaria de saber como eu faço para chamar essas dependências de uma forma simples. pois eu estou utilizando esse tipo de chamada:

```
import 'node_modules/chosen-js/chosen.jquery.js';
import 'node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js';
import 'node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js';
```

e na pasta css:

```
@import '../node_modules/css/font-awesome.min.css';
@import '../node_modules/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
@import '../node_modules/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
@import '../node_modules/slick/slick.css';
```

Vi alguma coisa sobre require e tals, porém não entendi muito bem como funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

root@sdv7 [~/node/node_modules/live_webcam]# npm install body-parser --save

Todos os módulos instalados são dentro de node_modules então para chamar fica como abaixo:

No seu arquivo Node APP :

```
    const   bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
```

A variavel bodyParser passa a conter os métodos do módulo. Eu uso assim sou novo em node mas acho que está correto!

Abraços